# get Infotip via command line

Tags: python, windows, powershell, command-line

How do I programmatically get the Infotip data for a particular exe file in Win7?

I am referring to the popup box that you see when hovering over a filename in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example script that pulls that data from `System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo` and `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$path = "C:\example\file.exe"
$versioninfo = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($path)
$itemproperties= get-childitem $path
[pscustomobject]@{
    "File Description" = $versioninfo.FileDescription
    Company = $versioninfo.CompanyName
    "File version" = $versioninfo.FileVersion
    "Date created" = $itemproperties.CreationTime
    Size = "$($itemproperties.length/1kb) kb"
}
```